# Is it able to call multiple drawcalls of vkCmdDrawIndexed in one render pass containing one pipeline?

Tags: graphics, rendering, vulkan

I have two meshes, containing same material template but with different paramters. I want to draw these two meshes one by one. For example, the pseudocode likes

```
BeginRenderPass
BindPipeline

for(auto& mesh : meshes)
{
    BindVertexBuffers(mesh.vertexBuffer)
    AddUniformBufferDescriptorSet(mesh.material)
    UpdateDescriptorSets
    BindIndexBuffer(mesh.indexBuffer)
    DrawIndexed(mesh.indexCount, 1, 0, 0, 0)
}

vkCmdEndRenderPass
```

I bind vertex buffers of all mesh to same binding index, and use same descriptor set for all uniform object. There are some validation errors:

validation layer: Validation Error: [ UNASSIGNED-CoreValidation-DrawState-InvalidCommandBuffer-VkDescriptorSet ] Object 0: handle = 0x40b43c0000000049, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DESCRIPTOR_SET; Object 1: handle = 0x1c40e53df48, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER; | MessageID = 0xe8616bf2 | You are adding vkCmdBindVertexBuffers() to VkCommandBuffer 0x1c40e53df48[] that is invalid because bound VkDescriptorSet 0x40b43c0000000049[] was destroyed or updated.

How can I implement the above pseudocode ?

Comment: "*bound VkDescriptorSet 0x40b43c0000000049[] was destroyed or updated*" Doesn't that tell you what you did, and that it has nothing to do with the draw function?

Comment: @NicolBolas No, I just find out it is caused by misuage of vulkan API. I will explain in the below anwser

Comment: "*I just find out it is caused by misuage of vulkan API.*" Yes. A "misusage" where you had a descriptor set bound and then updated it. *Exactly like* the error message says.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is my finding(**WRONG**). ~~First, the conclusion is I can not implment mulitple draw calls like the above pseudocode.~~ Because, according to [vkUpdateDescriptorSets](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/vkUpdateDescriptorSets.html) , it will invalid the command buffer used to bind the descriptor sets, which will disenable record next call. Therefore, the validation error appears.

##### What I can implement to draw multiple meshes with seperate material parameters.

There are two ways:

- Use push_constant in shader to config material parameters, and set the corresponding parameter values by vkCmdPushConstants before draw call.
- Use uniform buffer array in shader, where each element is a set of material parameters. Add an additional input attribute named “material id” to index the corresponding uniform buffer. Then update the uniform buffer array in one call of vkUpdateDescriptorSets. The current command buffer still can record next draw call command.

The first way is inspired by [Sascha_Willems](https://community.khronos.org/t/how-to-draw-meshes-with-different-material-parameters-in-one-render-pass/107766), the second way is what I have successfully implemented.

##### Supplement(CORRECTION)

I also try to update and bind the corresponding descriptor set before each of two draw calls insider one render pass. Finally, it works. Note that two seperate descriptor sets with same layout bindings need to be created, but the graphics pipeline need to be decleared to contain only one descriptor set.

Comment: You can also have multiple descriptor sets and switch between them for different objects. You can also use dynamic descriptors. There are a lot more than just two options.

Comment: @NicolBolas I think it can not do "switch descriptor sets" insider one render pass for each  draw call. Descrptor sets allocated for the pipeline should be all bound before draw call. Or there will be validation error, which I supplement to my answer.  Dynamic descriptor sets seem have the same result.

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong with them. It is 100% OK to switch descriptor sets between draw calls, so long as you're switching them with sets that have compatible layouts.

Comment: @NicolBolas Ok, I will keep in mind and try again in free time. If I succeed to implement switching descriptor set, I will update the supplement part.